# Xpages ajax request impacts context history

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus, xpages-ssjs

I have a simple Xpage (page1.xsp) opened from view.xsp page. It contains the following elements 
1) Back button written in SSJS

```
context.redirectToPreviousPage()
```

2) CSJS script that does ajax get every x minutes

```
dojo.xhr.get({
    url:"page2.xsp?param1=value1",
    handleAs:"text"  
});
```

My probem is that after several ajax requests my Back button goes to page2.xsp (ajax get page) instead of view.xsp.

How can I make it go back to view.xsp page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button and XHR behave very different in different browsers, so I wouldn't rely on it. Relying on a session variable is - as you pointed out - could become messy. So this is what I would do: store the page to return to in a session variable (yes), but only to hand it over to the page the very moment.

Pack it into a script tag using `var whereToGoBackTo = '${sessionScope.theLastPageCameFrom}'` and store it client side. Since it is only evaluated on first page load, it doesn't matter if it gets changed by other tabs later. Then use CSJS to navigate back.

You could consider an URL parameter, but I'd rather keep my URL clean

Comment: Stephan, yours approach sounds nice:)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but when I've had a "form" accessed from multiple "views" and want to know which one to go back to, I store it in `sessionScope` when opening the "form" and then just access that `sessionScope` variable.

Comment: Paul,  I've considered this option. But you know - many start views, many tabs open and you got a mess :)

Comment: I agree, it depends on application usage model